# Convert enum inside a Room query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an enum type `TagState` that has a working `TypeConverter`; I want the enum to be converted inside `@Query`, without it being an argument of a function.

I'm only interested in `firstInactiveOrNull()`. This works:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE state == :state LIMIT 1")
abstract suspend fun firstOrNull(state: TagState): TagEntity?

@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE state == 0 LIMIT 1")
suspend fun firstInactiveOrNull() = firstOrNull(TagState.INACTIVE)
```

But for the sake of clarity and gaining knowledge, I want to get rid of `firstOrNull()` and have a single function `firstInactiveOrNull()`.

Since I know TagState.INACTIVE is the first item, a possible solution would be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE state == 0 LIMIT 1")
abstract suspend fun firstInactiveOrNull(): TagEntity?
```

This is however - to me - not robust enough.

Is it possible to let Room generate a function with such a query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE state == {TagState.INACTIVE} LIMIT 1")
abstract suspend fun firstInactiveOrNull(): TagEntity?
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with room

the best thing you can do is use default argument and write your function like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE state =:tagState LIMIT 1")
suspend fun firstInactiveOrNull(tagState: Int?=TagState.INACTIVE): TagEntity?
```

now if you call the function   `firstInactiveOrNull()` it will by default give inactive tags but if you call `firstInactiveOrNull(TagState.ACTIVE)` it will give active tags . So as long as you don't pass argument it should be ok

Comment: What would you suggest for the function name in that case? `firstInactiveOrNull(TagState.ACTIVE)` does not return what the name suggests, so that would be faulty.

Comment: If you want the naming to be right then it will be like `firstOrNullTagReturnsInActiveTagIfNothingIsPassed` xD . If you want name to be Proper the don't take default argument and give function name like `firstOrNullTagWithState` and pass state every where . I don't see any other proper way

Comment: Alright, thanks! In that case I'll keep the solution I already had.